# Java Graphics and Bordering Problems in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, border, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have found a [`CustomScrollbarUIExample`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12270067/230513), and I am trying to change it completely into my own (with [attribution](https://stackexchange.com/legal), of course, this is legal). I have immediately run into a problem.

What I am trying to achieve is put a border around not the `JScrollPane` itself, but the moveable block if you understand what I meen.

I have put the modified source code below, and I have highlighted my problem.

```
package com.finn.chess;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12270067/230513 */
public class CustomScrollbarUIExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JScrollPane before = makeExamplePane();
    JScrollPane after = makeExamplePane();
    after.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    JScrollBar sb = after.getVerticalScrollBar();
    sb.setUI(new MyScrollbarUI());
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    f.add(before);
    f.add(after);
    f.pack();
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

private static JScrollPane makeExamplePane() {
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(16, 16);
    text.append("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet…");
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
    return scroll;
}

static class MyScrollbarUI extends MetalScrollBarUI {

    private Image imageThumb, imageTrack;
    private JButton b = new JButton() {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(0, 0);
        }

    };

    MyScrollbarUI() {
        imageThumb = FauxImage.create(32, 32, Color.blue.brighter());
        imageTrack = FauxImage.create(32, 32, Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintThumb(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle r) {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        ((Graphics2D) g).drawImage(imageThumb,
            r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintTrack(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle r) {
        ((Graphics2D) g).drawImage(imageTrack,
            r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected JButton createDecreaseButton(int orientation) {
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    protected JButton createIncreaseButton(int orientation) {
        return b;
    }
}

private static class FauxImage {

    static public Image create(int w, int h, Color c) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
        g2d.setPaint(c);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        
        // THIS IS MY PROBLEM, THE BORDER
        g2d.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.drawRect(0, 0, w-1, h-1);
        
        g2d.dispose();
        return bi;
    }
}
}
```

Just at the end, you can see that I setup a border to put around it.
But in big sizes, it appears like this:

[image: Scroll bar]

I don't want that massive block of white down the bottom; I want a simple, one pixel high border.
How do I achieve this?
Also I am posting a brand new thread because the other one was 2 years old, and I can't add ALL this into a comment.

Comment: *"Also I am posting a brand new thread because the other one.."*  What one?  Please provide a link.

Comment: It clearly states at the top of my source.

Comment: /** @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12270067/230513 */

Comment: And now you've extracted the link from the source, look over at the **Linked** section on the right hand side.  (Now it *appears* as a 'linked' question..)

Comment: I don't understand. Is that a bad thing?

Comment: If I knew what 'that' referred to, I might be able to answer.

Comment: 'that' meaning the fact that the question is now a 'linked' question?

Comment: No, that's a good thing.  It provides links in both threads & makes it easy for people reading either thread to see the connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the border in `paintThumb()`, *after* the image has been scaled by `drawImage()`. Starting from the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12270067/230513) and using `Color.red` for emphasis, the result is seen below:

[image]

```
@Override
protected void paintThumb(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle r) {
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(imageThumb, r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height, null);
    g2d.setPaint(Color.red);
    g2d.drawRect(r.x, r.y, r.width - 1, r.height);
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Cheers trashgod. Answering to your own code xD. I appreciate it.

Comment: Uh oh. I just tried with Color.WHITE on a BLACK background, and when I scroll up, it clips. So theres like a white trail left behind. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: It's alright. Just changed the code at the bottom for the drawRect(); Add - 1 to r.height so...

g2d.drawRect(r.x, r.y, r.width - 1, r.height - 1);

Comment: @user3636058: This sounds reasonable; the `Graphics` API says, "Operations that draw the outline of a figure operate by traversing an infinitely thin path between pixels with a pixel-sized pen that hangs down and to the right of the anchor point on the path."