# why scrollbar thumb travel too far in Nimbus LnF?

Tags: java, swing, nimbus, jscrollbar

I am creating **custom** Scrollbar. I found the **thumb** will travel **into** half of the end **buttons** on the track when I change to **Nimbus** LnF. On **MetalLookAndFeel**, the **thumb** will stop right before the end **buttons**.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Here is a [working code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265740/make-a-custom-jscrollbar-using-an-image) . Please use the second answer's code and do three changes: **1**. use Nimbus LnF; **2**. comment out createDecreaseButton() and createIncreaseButton() methods; **3**. make **MyScrollbarUI** class extends **BasicScrollBarUI**

Comment: If you're using Nimbus, can't you just skin it? See [Nimbus Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html) (Nimbus is based on Synth Look and Feel)

Comment: I am not really understand the "skin" here. What I want to do is make the scrollbar "flat".

Comment: Nimbus, been based on Sythn, has a CSS like language which can be used to modify the UI (or "skin" it) without the need to write (a lot) of more code.  I suggest you  have a look at the links above

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thank you for your link. I think I found the solution for this issue based on the link you gave to me. I am trying to head the right direction you pointed. But I have issues you may can help me. Please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785063/how-to-implement-painter-to-use-my-image-for-the-scrolllbar-button-in-nimbus-lnf

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for MadProgrammer. He points me to the right direction and I found the solution:

ScrollBar.decrementButtonGap and ScrollBar.incrementButtonGap properties will control these gaps.